# How to divide multiple figures to multiple pages with \ContinuedFloat?

Tags: floats, subfloats

I have the following code for the my figures which works fine:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.17]{MergedSDroplet_CA5_Bo0}} 
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.17]{MergedSDroplet_CA5_Bo15}}
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.17]{MergedSDroplet_CA5_Bo100}}
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.17]{MergedSDroplet_CA5_Bo700}}
    \caption{Coalescence results for $5^{\circ}$ contact angle case. Simulations with (a) Bo $= 0$, (b) Bo $= 15$, (c) Bo $= 100$, (d) Bo $= 700$}
    \label{fig:ND_SMergedResults_CA5}
\end{figure}
```

However, this is way too large for a page that includes some text. I want to divide these figures as I see fit into two pages. Such as 1 figure to the end of page 1, and the rest to the next page, or 2 figure to the page 1 and the rest to the next page. I could not really manage to solve this problem and I am in need of dire help.

PS: Using below code works, but it also captions first two subfigures, which I don't want:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.17]{MergedSDroplet_CA5_Bo0}}
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.17]{MergedSDroplet_CA5_Bo15}}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]\ContinuedFloat
    \centering
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.17]{MergedSDroplet_CA5_Bo100}}
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.17]{MergedSDroplet_CA5_Bo700}}
    \caption{Coalescence results for $5^{\circ}$ contact angle case. Simulations with (a) Bo $= 0$, (b) Bo $= 15$, (c) Bo $= 100$, (d) Bo $= 700$}
    \label{fig:ND_SMergedResults_CA5}
\end{figure}
```

Thank you in advance, for any solution.
Have a great day!

Comment: From the code fragments you included, I guess, you currently use the `subfigure` package in order to number your images. Please be aware that this packages is considered obsolete. You might want to switch to `subfig` or `subcaption` instead.

Answer (score 1):

With the `subfig` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.17]{MergedSDroplet_CA5_Bo0}}
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.17]{MergedSDroplet_CA5_Bo15}}
    \phantomcaption
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\ContinuedFloat
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.17]{MergedSDroplet_CA5_Bo100}}
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.17]{MergedSDroplet_CA5_Bo700}}
    \caption{Coalescence results for $5^{\circ}$ contact angle case. Simulations with (a) Bo $= 0$, (b) Bo $= 15$, (c) Bo $= 100$, (d) Bo $= 700$}
    \label{fig:ND_SMergedResults_CA5}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

With the `subcaption` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.17]{MergedSDroplet_CA5_Bo0}}
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.17]{MergedSDroplet_CA5_Bo15}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\ContinuedFloat
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.17]{MergedSDroplet_CA5_Bo100}}
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.17]{MergedSDroplet_CA5_Bo700}}
    \caption{Coalescence results for $5^{\circ}$ contact angle case. Simulations with (a) Bo $= 0$, (b) Bo $= 15$, (c) Bo $= 100$, (d) Bo $= 700$}
    \label{fig:ND_SMergedResults_CA5}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

The output of both examples is the following:

[image]

Comment: This worked like a charm. I also switched to subfig package which appear to be more convenient. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hello once again, right now this \Continuedfloat keeps going on with other following figures, how can I break it?

Comment: @Peclet: I unfortunately don't undastand what "keeps going on with other following figures" means in this context.

Comment: I figured it out by switching  to subcaption package. The numbering for my figure set should end at "(d)". However, when I add another figure, it was labeled as "(e)", "(f)" etc. instead of starting from "(a)".

Comment: If I take one of the MWEs from my answer, copy the code from the first `\begin{figure}` to the second `\end{figure}` and place the copied code right before `\end{document}`, I end up with the expected output, which is figure 1 with subfigures a) to d)  and figure 2 with subfigures a) to d).